# Querying multiple postgres tables in python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to query multiple sql tables and store them as pandas dataframe.

```
cur = conn.cursor()
  cur.execute("select relname from pg_class where relkind='r' and relname !~ '^(pg_|sql_)';")
  tables_df = cur.fetchall()
  ##table_name_list = tables_df.table_name 
  select_template = ' SELECT * FROM {table_name}'
  frames_dict = {}
  for tname in tables_df :
      query = select_template.format(table_name = tname)
      frames_dict [tname] = pd.read_sql ( query , conn)
```

But I'm getting error like :

```
 DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql ' SELECT * FROM ('customer',)': syntax 
 error at or near "'yesbank'"
`enter code here`LINE 1:  SELECT * FROM ('customer',)
```

Customer is name of table in my databse that i get from line

```
 tables_df = cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: It's `format()` not `formate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Per your error, looks like you have a typo in the word format:

```
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'formate'
```

Try

```
query = select_template.format(table_name = tname)
```

Comment: thanks  , now i am getting execution error , probably its some silly mistake but i am new to programming , so ....